# vuejs yup vuelidate type checkbox

Tags: vue.js, yup

I have a problem. Even if a type checked vuelidate value is false, I can send a reference and error massage does not appear. How can I ensure that the value is true?

```
      rizaOnayi: Yup.boolean().required().label("Açık Rıza Onayi"),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

this one is for strict check

> rizaOnayi: Yup.boolean().true().required().label("Açık Rıza Onayi"),

> rizaOnayi: Yup.boolean().truthy().required().label("Açık Rıza Onayi"),